# How to find vscode installed path in ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, file-association, filezilla, filetype

I am trying to change the FileZilla filetype association and set vscode as default for any filetype. I couldn't find installed application path or executable file to give a path. How do I make vscode the default executable for all filetypes?

Comment: How do you run vscode now?   Do you have a shortcut to it?   Why can't you just look at the shortcut?   Can you run it from CMD?   Look in every directory in your PATH.

Comment: @Scott hes using Ubuntu not Windows

Comment: The basic question remains — how does the OP run vscode now?

Comment: @Scott thats not how linux works.  his $path is probably empty.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

By default, the executable is `/usr/bin/code`

If for some reason it was installed in a different directory, from a terminal type:

```
which code
```

And it will tell you the path to the executable.

Comment: it is in snap/bin/code.

Comment: @mounika ah, you installed the snap version, not the DEB installer

Answer (score 3):

I wasn't able to find it using

```bsh
which code
```

I was able to find it using

```bsh
whereis code
```

This is running PopOS 20.04

Answer (score 1):

If you used snap to install it, then it will be at /snap/bin/code, but if you didn't use snap or did not find it there, then just execute this command:-

```
which code
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use [vscodium](https://vscodium.com/) which is visual studio code without the microsoft spying, then the path is `/usr/bin/codium` by using `which codium`

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).